# Configuring Tomcat with HTTPs

Tags: tomcat, https

I want to configure Tomcat with HTTPs as part of one of our projects' requirements. I have very little understanding of HTTPs and SSL Certificates.
I have created a self signed certificate and I have started Tomcat Server on port 8443 but I can still see a warning message in the browser (Screenshot below). Is it due to the fact that its a self signed certificate and not generated by a legal CA?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. That exception is only because you created a self-signed certificate.